# Find surface area of the portion of the planar surface $S(u,v)=<u,v,1-u-v>$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Where $(u,v)$ belong to the triangle in the $uv$-plane with vertices $(0,0) (1,0) (0,1)$. 
I am completely stuck here!! I am sure I will use double integrals (or at least I think so) and also the triangle vertices to find the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The height of your surface can be thought of as the function $$f(u,v) = 1-u-v$$ and you need to find the area of that surface over a triangular region in the $uv$-plane, bounded by $u \ge 0, v \ge 0$ and $u+v \le 1$.

Here is your region:

[image]

Can you set up the area as a problem in integration?

Comment: thank you for the hint! I am kinda confused is is going to be a double integral? if yes, are the boundaries going to be for U from 0 to 1 and for V from 0 to u-1?